# Website image management via JavaScript - what's a good way to handle this?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

I'm making an administration page for a website.  Currently, it allows a user to see a set of "products" which they can delete, edit, or add to (create new).  Addition and editing both work by allowing the user to fill out/edit values on a form which is presented on top of the screen using some javascript/css.

The issue that I've run into is that I need to allow the administrator to select an image to associate with the product they're creating or editing with this form.  To make things easy for now, let us assume that all selectable images are already held in the folder "ROOT/images".

How can I provide a nice interface for the user to select an image from the server on this form?  I can't send all the images down with the webpage in advance in case there end up being thousands, and I don't know how to let the web page on the client side access things on the server side through javascript.

I'm restricted to using {PHP/MySql/JavaScript (w/ jQuery if I need it)/HTML/CSS} - can anyone give me an idea on how to accomplish this task, or what the common alternate way around this problem is?

Comment: Restricted to *just* the standard web technologies? That's harsh.

Comment: Yeah, yeah :p if i didn't put that you can bet that some of the answers would have been out of bounds though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're basically asking for a directory listing that is available via javascript.

So you could write a PHP script that lists the images as an json encoded array.

That script could handle additional actions like search and paginate, so you don't need to transfer too much data (at once).

Comment: This sounds good, but it's a little over my head - could you explain a little more or send a link to a decent example/tutorial? I don't quite understand how the php script could be used to select images from the page without navigating away from it being that php is server-side.  Or are you suggesting the javascript somehow calls the php script and has it return a value to it maybe?

Comment: Yes, the javascript calls the script via AJAX (jQuery has that), so it's basically a remote procedure call returning the directory listing.

Comment: @w00te, since you're new to PHP and JavaScript I thought I would mention that PHP has a [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function to convert things to JSON and JavaScript has the [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON) method to turn JSON data into JS objects.  If you are using jQuery you could also use [`jQuery.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).

Comment: Thanks man, that sounds helpful - ill read up on it tomorrow morning :)

Answer (score 3):

If there are literally thousands of images, there is no use in displaying them all on one page. I (personally) can't process *that* many images at once and make a valid choice among them (let alone wait for them all to load).

I'd try and assign a tagging system to the images (if possible) and make an interface that simplifies the process:

```
Search for an product: __________________ [ search ]

Results:
 ______      ______      ______      ______ 
|      |    |      |    |      |    |      |
|      |    |      |    |      |    |      |
|      |    |      |    |      |    |      |
|______|    |______|    |______|    |______|

 ______      ______      ______      ______ 
|      |    |      |    |      |    |      |
|      |    |      |    |      |    |      |
|      |    |      |    |      |    |      |
|______|    |______|    |______|    |______|

                [ See more... ]
```

You can use jQuery to make the interface fancy (the images load as you type, the `See more...` button loads 8 more images and they fade in, useless sliding, etc.)

An alternative would be to scrape an image site. If the images are of products, you *could* scrape Amazon for the query and load their images. But you might run into copyright issues if you use their images (I have no idea).

Comment: thanks man, +1 since I'll probably use this kind of interface along with the other answer.  I like the the animation suggestions to make it look more professional.

Comment: Sort of like a icon view in a file manager? I like that idea.

Comment: Exactly what I was hoping to achieve :) I've always been a C++/non-web C# programmer though, so I'm still trying to wrap my head around how to achieve certain things in a web domain.  Takes some practice to think about everything in terms of server-side/client-side when making a gui. :)

Comment: I do it the other way around, truthfully. I find it easier to implement the serverside technology and then find a way to make it accessible to the user. But that's just my method...